# A simple Cpp Project with Unittest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, hudson, xunit

Have anywhere here a simple project (really simple) project for me in C++.

Becaus i am testing Jenkins and i would to start my Unittest from there to see what Jenkins is doing.

For help Thanks you!

best regards 
MemaAa

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the unittest framework you're gonna use! Anyway the basics are the same.
Have a look at [cpptest](http://cpptest.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html)

Comment: i have a very simpel C++ Project.   int a = 5     int b = 5  and want to make a unittest. the test will be: is a==b yes it is oder no it isn't